# Conditionally enable Maven extension?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

We would like to try out the [Maven Build Cache Extension](https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/getting-started.html), which you can enable by putting the following in `.mvn/extensions.xml`:

```xml
<extension>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-build-cache-extension</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</extension>
```

However until we have confidence that this doesn't introduce problems, we would like it disabled by default and then only enabled when you set a flag on the command line.

But [the documentation for extensions.xml](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-extensions-xml-file) does not specify any way to conditionally enable/disable specific extensions.

How can I conditionally enable or disable a Maven extension?

Comment: Simple answer: You can't... The simplest solution is to rename the `extension.xml` into something different...

Comment: Hmm could I name it `conditional_extensions.xml` and then use the command line to specify the extensions file perhaps...

Comment: Perhaps I could use `.mvn/maven-build-cache-config.xml` which [has an enabled property](https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/build-cache-config.html#class_configuration).

Comment: Ah... here: `-Dmaven.build.cache.remote.enabled=(true/false)` (https://maven.apache.org/extensions/maven-build-cache-extension/parameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found one [blog](https://javastreets.com/blog/maven/maven-build-cache-extension.html#:%7E:text=Disable%20cache,-If%20for%20some&text=The%20other%20way%20is%20to,when%20executing%20any%20maven%20goal.) mentioning about how to disable **Maven Build Cache**.

Please read the above blog. It has all the information that you are looking for.

You can do it via both **XML** and **Command Line**.

1. **Command Line** :

   ```
   mvn clean install -Dmaven.build.cache.enabled=false
   ```
2. **XML** (`.mvn/maven-build-cache-config.xml`):

   ```
   <cache xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/BUILD-CACHE-CONFIG/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/build-cache-config-1.0.0.xsd">
      ........
      .............
      <configuration>
        <enabled>false</enabled>
      </configuration>
   </cache>
   ```